# Issues With Firebase Gradle Builds

Tags: android, firebase, gradle

So I have looked at a bunch of articles that have solutions to this but have not gotten any to work. I am getting an error with the using the Firebase Messaging and Firestore libraries with Google Pay Services Location and Maps. Whenever I build the project the following error gets returned:

> No virtual method zzbqp()Ljava/lang/String; in class
>   Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp; or its super classes (declaration of
>   'com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp' appears in
>   /data/app/skutl.me.client-P4tdXC_WHOrJdSuzHJKp9Q==/base.apk)

Below are my gradle configuration files:

> Top Level Project File

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    } }

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }
        google()
    } }

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir }
```

> App Build File

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "skutl.me.client"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'

    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:16.0.0'

    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2'


    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I've tried to make them all the same level but none of the libraries have the same versions for v15 or v16. Any insight into these errors?

Comment: You should be using [firebase-ui-auth:3.3.1](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/releases)

Comment: where is `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'`

Comment: Thank you Bob and James! That with what Levi stated resolved the issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.3'
```

to this

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.3.1'
```

That's the proper version for firebase v15, see [repo](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android)

Also, as suggested by @JamesPoang you need firebase core:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'
```